# How to set ManyToOne relationship in Flask- SQL alchemy?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am new to Flask and SQLalchmey. I am trying to crate two tables and establish a `manytoone` relationship between them.

Here is what I did.

**table_hub**

```
      class Hub(db.Model):
          __tablename__ = 'hub'

          id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
          name = db.Column(db.String(),nullable=False,unique=True)
```

**tbl_vehicle**

```
      class vehileMaster(db.Model):
          __tablename__ = 'res.vehicle'

          id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
          name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
          hub_id = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('hub.id'))
          hub = db.relationship('Hub')
```

Here is what I need to achieve,

1. while creating a new vehicle in table `res.vehicle` I need to choose a hub from the list of hubs.

I don't know whether what i already did is correct or not.

Comment: What is your actual question? Did you test your code?

Comment: @RobinUphoff This is my requirement. while creating a new vehicle in table res.vehicle I need to choose a hub from the list of hubs. And I not sure the code above I mentioned was correct or not? i need clarity about it.

Comment: could I help you with my answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

The standard way of implementing a foreign key relationship would be:

```
class Hub(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'hub'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False,unique=True)
    vehicles = db.relationship('res.vehicle', backref='hub', lazy=True)


class vehicleMaster(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'res.vehicle'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    hub_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('hub.id'))
```